# Echo variable with index

Tags: bash, shell, for

I set var inside loop, like this:

```
eval "PB_$i=`cat btc_pub_$i.key`"
```

where $i is the index of loop.

I want to do echo or printf of

```
$PB_$i ($PB_0,$PB_1, etc)
```

I tried with

```
echo $PB_${i}
```

but dosen't work

Comment: I think you may have left out the first part of your question on accident.  Can you expound on this issue?

Comment: How about an array: `pb[i]=$(cat btc_pub_$i.key); echo "${pb[i]}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a dereference:

```
$ foo=bar
$ bar=somewords
$ printf "The value of %s is '%s'\n" "${foo}" "${!foo}"
The value of bar is 'somewords'

$ var_1=foo
$ var_2=bar
$ for i in 1 2; do v="var_${i}"; printf "%s\n" "${!v}"; done
foo
bar
```

I might, though, suggest rather than using a series of numerically suffixed variables, look into an array:

```
$ var=("foo" "bar") # var[0]=foo; var[1]=bar
$ for v in ${var[@]}, do printf "%s\n" "${v}"; done
foo
bar
```